# Sequence no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've build an ASP.net MVC website with multiple pages and everything works. However they get an error message saying the sequence contains no elements when they try to post the page after leaving it open for a few moments (10 to 30 minutes) and doing some other work.

The form is build using the razor code: 
`@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Beoordeling", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "beoordelingForm" }))
{
...
}`

the controller method looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = allparameters")] object ObjectName)
 {
 }
```

Again this only occurs when leaving the page open for some time.
If they just use it when they open the page there are no complications.

This problem occurs with all my ASP.NET MVC websites.

I think this is a setting / default behaviour of the form to post but can someone please explain why it gives the error message.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Sequence contains no elements Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no elements
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.  Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +264

Comment: where's your linq call?

Comment: I think this might be because of ValidateAntiForgeryToken, it creates a cookie to be validated on the server side, I think after the time you mentioned the cookie has been expired.

Comment: This error only occurs when posting the form so there is no linq call as far as I know. @DanielA.White .

Comment: @TiagoÁvila this could be but we need the AntiForgerytoken to check the data from the post

Answer (score 1):

"Sequence contains no elements" is raised when you attempt to call `Single`, `First`, etc. on an empty queryset. You have a few options in this scenario:

1. You can test that your queryset has *something* in it, first, using something like `Any`, i.e.:

   ```
   if (queryset.Any())
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You can simply use a try-catch to recover from the exception:

   ```
   try
   {
       var foo = queryset.First();
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException)
   {
       // handle it
   }
   ```
3. You can use `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc. instead. The `OrDefault` versions will simply return `null` rather than raising an exception if the queryset is empty. However, be sure to do proper null-checking, then, or you'll simply trade this exception for `NullReferenceException` instead.

Comment: Hi Chris, Unfortunally it happens on the post of a page which will send back a filled in object. We then do some checks on the object and save it in the database.  The problem is this error occurs when you leave the page open for some time. If it is a case of doing a check on the empty queryset then why is the form posting an empty object.

Comment: *Who knows?* There's no code here to tell you why that's occurring. We'd need to see your entire view and your action code.